# zebra barcode scanner Android studio integration

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

**Hey guys.. I'm building an Android App and I need to read bar-code from a zebra bar-code scanner connected via USB. When I scan a bar-code it appears in different places on my app..and even presses buttons. Has any one got any idea how can i get it into a string?

Comment: There is a lib that you scan bar-code directly from phone camera. If you wont to to scan trough USB scanner you should search in scanner documentatoins

Comment: Which scanner documentations? Android Scanner ? how is it connected?

Comment: Your USB Scanner should have some documentation. If you are interested in other way to scan bar-code there is an opportunity to scan those codes through android device camera

Answer (score 0):

Many scanners can emulate bar code key input by reading setting bar code.
You can also customize prefixes (indicating input from the barcode scanner or barcode type) or finally with a return key.
By doing so, it is possible for the application to perform processing such as determining the field to be input, using the barcode type and part of the barcode data itself, and writing the data.
Please check the user's guide of the Zebra bar code scanner you are about to use.